# UknownHostException while trying to post a message to facebook

Tags: android, facebook

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.facebook.com": No address associated with hostname
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:400)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:441)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:215)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:751)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:688)
at com.nammari.FinalActivity$1.onClick(FinalActivity.java:62)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check you internet connnectivity

Comment: does the device have access to the internet and can it contact a DNS server ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your manifest file, add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have added this permission then also i got same Error, Is there any Problem in Emulator

Answer (score 0):

I think the answear of Raghav Sood on the following question will be helpfull.He describes the 3 reasons that you would get this exception

[Error on post message to the facebook wall in android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560444/error-on-post-message-to-the-facebook-wall-in-android-4-0-3)

Comment: Answer with links only are generally discouraged. Could you update your answer with a brief summary of what answer will be found in the link?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the emulator. I got same error too. I had it working 2 days ago and today I launched an app and got above error, after looking solutions mentioned above and here [Error on post message to the facebook wall in android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560444/error-on-post-message-to-the-facebook-wall-in-android-4-0-3) I had everything correct.

At the end I just killed my emulator and restarted and error went away, I guess stale session cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must reset your network

I hope this work for you:

- Click Start =>Run, type in CMD, press OK.
- Copy and paste this into the Command prompt:
- netsh winsock reset catalog
- Press Enter
- Then copy and paste this in:
- netsh int ip reset reset.log
- Press Enter.
- When finished restart your computer.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oCUYZsG8VJU