# Error on post message to the facebook wall in android 4.0.3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-post

I try to post message on user facebook wall. It's work on previous platform versions, but on Android 4.0.3 I have error:

```
    07-19 14:53:02.945: W/System.err(29740): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "graph.facebook.com": No address associated with hostname
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:436)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:441)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
07-19 14:53:02.965: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:193)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:751)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at com.koloneme.socialnetworking.FacebookUtility.postOnWall(FacebookUtility.java:115)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at com.koloneme.socialnetworking.FacebookUtility.facebookAuthorization(FacebookUtility.java:65)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at com.koloneme.socialnetworking.FacebookActivity.onCreate(FacebookActivity.java:33)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:421)
07-19 14:53:02.975: W/System.err(29740):    ... 33 more
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 105) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1889)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$8500(WebViewCore.java:973)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2088)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendViewSizeZoom(WebView.java:3450)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:679)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1900(ZoomManager.java:59)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1174)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:607)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-19 14:53:03.075: W/webcore(29740):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using this facebook sdk  -https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

Here is my code to posting message on wall:

```
 private static void postOnWall(String msg) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Testing graph API wall post");
             try {
                 //   String response = facebook.request("me");
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("message", msg);
                    parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
                    String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                            "POST");
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "got response: " + response);
                    if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                            response.equals("false")) {
                       Log.v(LOGTAG, " error Blank response");
                    }
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three reasons that you would get this exception:

1. You have not declared the internet permission in your manifest
2. The device does not have an internet connection, or has one which blocks facebook access at the DNS level. Try using a home network if you're behind a company porxy.
3. Facebook's server's are temporarily not working.

Comment: Thanks for your the answer, but device is connected to the internet, all permissions are added, native facebook app is working and before post message on wall user authorization is successful.

Comment: Problem was in internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

i get

got response: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}